# Apply some condition on jsonnode and filter resultset in Java

Tags: java, json, jsonnode

I have an array of Jsonnodes. something like that

```
[
 {
   "coupon": "VAR",
   "currency": "USD",
   "sip": "94989WAX5",
   "lastModifiedDate": "2022-09-23T08:16:25Z"
  },
  {
   "coupon": "VAR1",
   "currency": "USD",
   "sip": "94989WAX5",
   "lastModifiedDate": "2022-09-21T08:16:25Z"
  },
  {
   "coupon": "VAR3",
   "currency": "USD",
   "sip": "XHBRYWEB1",
   "lastModifiedDate": "2022-09-20T08:16:25Z"
  }
 ]
```

I have a requirement, if the sip value of two nodes are same then I need to pick only that sip which lastModifiedDate is latest. In above example the final output should be remaining two nodes.

```
 [
  {
   "coupon": "VAR",
   "currency": "USD",
   "sip": "94989WAX5",
   "lastModifiedDate": "2022-09-23T08:16:25Z"
  },
  {
   "coupon": "VAR3",
   "currency": "USD",
   "sip": "XHBRYWEB1",
   "lastModifiedDate": "2022-09-20T08:16:25Z"
  }
 ]
```

I was try to solve it by creating `HashMap<String,JsonNode>` where Sip is the key and the JsonNode is complete node. It doesn't seems to be a cleaner way. is there any other way to achieve it. I am using `fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode`

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, JsonNode> map =
    jsonNodeList.stream()
        .collect(
            toMap(
                jsonNode -> jsonNode.get("sip").asText(),
                jsonNode -> jsonNode,
                (jsonNode1, jsonNode2) -> {
                  boolean after =
                      LocalDateTime.parse(String.valueOf(jsonNode1.get("lastModifiedDate")))
                          .isAfter(
                              LocalDateTime.parse(
                                  String.valueOf(jsonNode2.get("lastModifiedDate"))));
                  return after ? jsonNode1 : jsonNode2;
                },
                HashMap::new));
```

Comment: I really dislike Java 8. It's supposed to be more readable, but all I see is one long run-on sentence.

Comment: what? it is a declarative method chaining. and what version of Java are you programming on?

Comment: 11, but I never use the Java 8 stuff, all my colleagues do. It's not more readable, it's like can I please get a statement termination and a line break please, you know so I can catch my breath.

Comment: Stream API was provided not because of readability reasons and it is pretty readable if you know what is what and how it works IMHO. what programming languages have you ever used apart from Java?
btw I like @Raymond Choi's answer

Comment: Yes I know, I doubt the development team at Oracle would make that the driving force behind their proposals.

Comment: Yours is a good answer too, I just don't like Java 8. My colleagues would praise you so much for your Java 8 code, also I work with JavaScript/React there's a lot of syntax like that too.  map, filter, some etc...

Comment: well, it's a bit of functional programming and declarative approach in the imperative language that Java actually is, It's compact now, add a self-explaining method name or even a small comment taking into account most of all a quite low possibility that someone would have to dig again around this code next N months or years

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248438/discussion-between-pavlo-kuchereshko-and-wpw).

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/octomix/josson

Deserialization

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "[" +
    " {" +
    "   \"coupon\": \"VAR\"," +
    "   \"currency\": \"USD\"," +
    "   \"sip\": \"94989WAX5\"," +
    "   \"lastModifiedDate\": \"2022-09-23T08:16:25Z\"" +
    "  }," +
    "  {" +
    "   \"coupon\": \"VAR1\"," +
    "   \"currency\": \"USD\"," +
    "   \"sip\": \"94989WAX5\"," +
    "   \"lastModifiedDate\": \"2022-09-21T08:16:25Z\"" +
    "  }," +
    "  {" +
    "   \"coupon\": \"VAR3\"," +
    "   \"currency\": \"USD\"," +
    "   \"sip\": \"XHBRYWEB1\"," +
    "   \"lastModifiedDate\": \"2022-09-20T08:16:25Z\"" +
    "  }" +
    " ]");
```

Transformation

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("group(sip)@.elements.findByMax(lastModifiedDate)");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
[ {
  "coupon" : "VAR",
  "currency" : "USD",
  "sip" : "94989WAX5",
  "lastModifiedDate" : "2022-09-23T08:16:25Z"
}, {
  "coupon" : "VAR3",
  "currency" : "USD",
  "sip" : "XHBRYWEB1",
  "lastModifiedDate" : "2022-09-20T08:16:25Z"
} ]
```